# NSDate detection with NSDataDetector work differently on iOS8 and iOS9

Tags: ios, nsdate, ios9, nsdatadetector

I tried to get a NSDate from a NSString, use next code :

```
NSString *string = @"Wednesday";
NSError *error = nil;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
if (!error) {
    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:string
                                         options:NSMatchingReportCompletion
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
    NSArray *dates = [matches valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSLog(@"%@", dates);
}
```

If my string is "today", "tomorrow" or any week day without time after that, in iOS 8 I get nothing, but iOS 9 return current day for "today", tomorrow from "tomorrow" and next week day from "week day". 
does anyone know how to unify the result?